# Load time is slow for IE/Edge, is it possible to reduce the number of inline-stylesheet of angular2-material?

Tags: angular-material2

IE/Edge's loading time is longer than Chrome and FF.

Application is running slow in IE/Edge, suspecting it is caused by too many inline-stylesheets been rendered into the DOM.

Is it possible to reduce the number of inline-stylesheets (e.g. put them in a single .css file) while remained looking good? Or any advice for improving material2 performance on IE/Edge?